# Submit button act as collapse and submit

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap-4

I have a form with some input fields (text-input). Then i have a button at the bottom that says "Continue" and inside the form is a collapse-div (bootstrap 4). When the button is clicked the button moves to the bottom and two checkboxes are visible.

My goal is to make this button act like this:

1. First time click, the div collapses open and two checkboxes are visible
2. The button moves down (working at this point) and the submit button changes text to "continue" to "Submit" and it should work as a submit button (not collapse the div again)

This is the code:

```html
<div class="collapse" id="collapseExample">
  <div class="form-check">
       <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="checkbox1">
       <label class="form-check-label" for="checkbox1">
           label for checkbox 1
       </label>

       <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="checkbox2">
       <label class="form-check-label" for="checkbox2">
            label for checkbox 2
       </label>
     </div>
 </div>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-lg" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseExample" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">Continue</button>
```

I could either use `jQuery` to remove the first button and append/add a submit button but what would be the best method (use the same button or remove it and append a new submit button). Something ala this:

```
$('button[data-toggle="collapse"]').click(function() {
        /* Remove the "continiue"-collapse button and append a new one */
    });
```

If someone have any idea it would be nice to get som input.

Thanks!

Comment: I think it is better to add 'CSS' and make JQuery to run, to explain what you mean.

Comment: What do you mean add 'CSS' ? To make the transition or..?

Comment: CSS of `form-check-input` & `form-check-label` & `collapse`